# How to prettify itemizing texts with lots of abbreviations and symbols?

Tags: itemize, acronyms

I have the following tex code in a 2 column article.

```
The multi-faceted evaluation scheme is defined as follows:

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep]
\item \textbf{Structural Measures}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
    \item \textbf{$\vert$V$\vert$}: \# distinct vertices, 
    \item \textbf{$\vert$E$\vert$}: \# distinct edges
    \item \textbf{\#c.c}: \# connected components, 
    \item \textbf{cycles}: whether the taxonmy is a Directed Acyclic Graph or the taxonomy contains cycles
    \end{itemize}   
\item \textbf{Comparison against Gold Standards}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
    \item \textbf{\#VC}: \# vectices in common with gold standard
    \item \textbf{\%VC}: vertex coverage (i.e. proportion of gold standard vertices covered by system)
    \item \textbf{\#EC}: \# edges in common with gold standard
    \item \textbf{\%EC}: edge coverage (i.e. proportion of gold standard edges covered by system)
    \item \textbf{:NE}: ratio of novel edges 
    \item \textbf{F\&M}: Cummulative  Fowlkes \& Mallows Measure (Fowlkes and Mallows, 1983; Velardi, 2013)
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

And it outputs something like this:

[image]

Due to the space limit from the 2 column article having this itemize within itemize is really ugly especially with all the terminology and abbreviations.

## **How should I rearrange these bullets so that they are more presentable?**

---

I've tried reducing the abbreviations by replacing `#` with `no. of` like this

```
The multi-faceted evaluation scheme is defined as follows:

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep]
\item \textbf{Structural Measures}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
    \item \textbf{$\vert$V$\vert$}: no. of distinct vertices, 
    \item \textbf{$\vert$E$\vert$}: no. of distinct edges
    \item \textbf{\#c.c}: no. of connected components, 
    \item \textbf{cycles}: whether the taxonmy is a Directed Acyclic Graph or the taxonomy contains cycles
    \end{itemize}   
\item \textbf{Comparison against Gold Standards}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
    \item \textbf{\#VC}: no. of vectices in common with gold standard
    \item \textbf{\%VC}: vertex coverage (i.e. proportion of gold standard vertices covered by system)
    \item \textbf{\#EC}: no. of edges in common with gold standard
    \item \textbf{\%EC}: edge coverage (i.e. proportion of gold standard edges covered by system)
    \item \textbf{:NE}: ratio of novel edges 
    \item \textbf{F\&M}: Cummulative  Fowlkes \& Mallows Measure (Fowlkes and Mallows, 1983; Velardi, 2013)
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

And the space issue is worsen:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered putting them into a tabular?

Comment: "cumulative" has only one "m".

Comment: I would use `$|\mathbf{V}|$` or simply `\textbf{|V|}`.

Comment: Instead of an `itemize` environment, try a `description`, and perhaps `\textnumero` instead of `no.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these kinds of lists, I like using the `\item` name as the right-aligned optional "bullet".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep]
\item \textbf{Structural Measures}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.3cm,noitemsep]
    \item [\textbf{$\vert$V$\vert$}:] \# distinct vertices, 
    \item [\textbf{$\vert$E$\vert$}:] \# distinct edges
    \item [\textbf{\#c.c}:] \# connected components, 
    \item [\textbf{cycles}:] whether the taxonmy is a Directed Acyclic Graph or the taxonomy contains cycles
    \end{itemize}   
\item \textbf{Comparison against Gold Standards}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.3cm,noitemsep]
    \item [\textbf{\#VC}:] \# vectices in common with gold standard
    \item [\textbf{\%VC}:] vertex coverage (i.e. proportion of gold standard vertices covered by system)
    \item [\textbf{\#EC}:] \# edges in common with gold standard
    \item [\textbf{\%EC}:] edge coverage (i.e. proportion of gold standard edges covered by system)
    \item [\textbf{:NE}:] ratio of novel edges 
    \item [\textbf{F\&M}:] Cummulative  Fowlkes \& Mallows Measure (Fowlkes and Mallows, 1983; Velardi, 2013)
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]